# SharePoint 2013 - Multiple lookup values not saved back to document library

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library

Encountered a strange case. The customer has a document library, and in that library a lookup column with multiple values. The column is called Tematikk.

[image: The lookup column Tematikk]

Here's the strange part: 
When the users create new documents, and select one or more values in the lookup column, it gets saved to the item. But when editing the properties on an existing document and selecting one or more values in the lookup column (see screenshot below), no values in this column gets saved back to the item. Other columns values are saved as expected.

[image]

After the user clicks Save in the properties form, the lookup column is still empty. The version number has incremented as expected (1.5), so a new minor version of the document has been saved:

[image]

This is a SharePoint Server 2013 farm, and was updated with the latest CU today. But still no difference.

Has anyone any clue on what might be going on here?

Thanks for any help and input!

Edit:

Here's the SchemaXml of the column from the two document libraries.

Original Document Library:

```
<Field Version="8" Name="SKTematikk" DisplayName="Tematikk" Type="LookupMulti" ColName="int6" StaticName="SKTematikk" SourceID="{fbad389c-5ddf-4f38-9239-b1065117dbbe}" RowOrdinal="0" ID="{b8491327-b927-49a9-a42e-1fdb4e1809c7}" Sortable="FALSE" Required="FALSE" ShowField="Title" List="{f8d9d011-25d2-43d1-bd07-7d2443ab46c2}" Group="" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE" WebId="fbad389c-5ddf-4f38-9239-b1065117dbbe" Mult="TRUE" RelationshipDeleteBehavior="None"/>
```

New Document Library:

```
<Field Version="4" Name="Tematikk" DisplayName="Tematikk" Type="LookupMulti" ColName="int7" StaticName="SKTematikk" SourceID="{fbad389c-5ddf-4f38-9239-b1065117dbbe}" RowOrdinal="0" ID="{b8491327-b927-49a9-a42e-1fdb4e1809c7}" Sortable="FALSE" Required="FALSE" ShowField="Title" List="{f8d9d011-25d2-43d1-bd07-7d2443ab46c2}" Group="" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE" WebId="fbad389c-5ddf-4f38-9239-b1065117dbbe" Mult="TRUE" RelationshipDeleteBehavior="None"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a test in my sharepoint 2013 with the latest issue. The lookup field works fine on my end. You could create a new library and check if the same issue exists.

I assume there could be some custom scripts in the edit page of this library. Edit the page and check if there is any script editor web part or content editor web part.

Comment: I did find a script editor on the edit page of this library. But removing it didn't help. (It was only CSS adjusting width on the list boxes.) I the created a new doclib and added the same column, and it worked as expected. But AFAICS, the column SchemaXml looks exactly the same. I've edited the original question and added them there.

Comment: This is weird. Please try to delete that lookup column and recreate it. Check if that works.